# Jquery getOffset function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, position, offset

```
function getContaineroffset(from){
    (from= 'diagonal') ? from= 'left' : from = 'top';

    var p = $("#container");
    var position = p.offset();

    return position.from;
}
```

I have function `getContaineroffset()` and I want to return for example: value of `position.left`.

This code returning `undefined`.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`.` operator is intended for use with *identifiers*. If you want to access object property by dynamic string you have to use `[]` notation.

So you have to replace:

```
return position.from;
```

with:

```
return position[from];
```

Comment: @user2992577 You could choose this answer as "accepted" if you want to express your gratitude.

Answer (score 1):

The function is setup in an awkward manner, and also won't behave as expected for a couple of reasons.

```
(from= 'diagonal') ? from= 'left' : from = 'top';
```

In the first part of the statement, you're assigning `'diagonal'` to `from`, rather than checking for equality.

This can also be simplified to something like this.

`from = (from === 'diagonal') ? 'left' : 'top';`

Lastly, `position.from` accesses the literal property `from` in `position`. If you want to access a property in position where the key is the value of `from`, you must use this syntax.

`position[from];`

I personally would implement the function as follows.

```
function getContainerOffset(from) {
    var property = (from === 'diagonal') ? 'left' : 'top';

    return $('#container').offset()[property];
}
```